# Angular ng-option filtering with a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

The following list want to bind in a drop down with condition `type="0"`

```
 $scope.ListPrintDestination = [{ id: "0", Name: "Printer",Type:"0" }, { id: "1", Name: "Windows" ,Type:"0"}, { id: "2", Name: "No Print" ,Type:"1"}];
```

then how will modify below code

```
<select ng-model="num" ng-options="lst as lst.AcNo for lst in lstPrint track by lst.AcNo">
    <option selected="selected">select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` for `Type='0'`, and in html iterate on `ListPrintDestination`.

**Demo:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.ListPrintDestination = [{
    id: "0",
    Name: "Printer",
    Type: "0"
  }, {
    id: "1",
    Name: "Windows",
    Type: "0"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    Name: "No Print",
    Type: "1"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="num" ng-options="lst as lst.Name for lst in ListPrintDestination | filter : {Type : '0'} ">
    <option selected="selected">select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```